# SQL Cast as Date (yyMMdd) does not work in a case statement but works in a select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am very curious, not sure if I missed something here.
But using Cast (yyMMdd) in a case statement throws an error

'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

But in a single select like below, it returns the result

```
 select case
     when ISDATE('000000') = 0 then 'False'
     else CAST('950705' as date)
  end [YEAR]--error on else



   select CAST('950705' as date) [Year]-- 1995-07-05 (works)
```

Comment: The problem is `'False'`. A `CASE` can only have a single type, and the type precedence rules of T-SQL here give it a type of `DATE` (your second expression) -- and of course `'False'` is not convertible. Consider using `TRY_CONVERT` rather than `ISDATE`, in any case.

Comment: Ref: [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not on the `else` but on the `then 'false'` - due to datatype precedence and that `case` can only return a single datatype.  you're trying to resturn a `date` and a `string`.

use `try_convert` or `try_cast`

```
select  try_cast('000000' as date)
        ,try_cast('950705' as date) as [YEAR]
```